# Cant send attribute in onclick in description of pushpin in bing maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bing-maps

I have a map with bing maps with some pushpin that they have html description. I would like when I click in this description (it is a list), call to an external function. This function is for create HTML description:

```
_getDescription = function (actions) {
    var description = "<div><ul class='action'>";
    actions.forEach(function (action) {
        description += '<li onclick="showOrderModal(action)"><strong>' + action.address.info.code + "</strong><br><span>" + action.address.info.address_for_pushpin + "</span>"
    })
    description += "</li></ul></div>"
    return description;
}
```

With this I set htmlContent with my description:

```
$scope.pinInfobox.setOptions({
        // title: e.target.Title,
        htmlContent: e.target.Description,
        visible:true,
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,25)
    });
```

I have `showOrderModal()` function and when I click in an item of the list, it says:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: action is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing makes sense. You have an HTML string that has a name of a property, but there is no actual link to the property. In this string:

```
'<li onclick="showOrderModal(action)"><strong>'
```

**action** is nothing more than a string. When someone clicks on the list item, the action value is undefined as there is no local value for that. What you need to do is include a some basic information that can be used to retrieve the information you want for the action. Perhaps store the array of actions somewhere and pass in the index of the action into the showOrderModal of each list item. For example:

```
var currentActions;

_getDescription = function (actions) {
    currentActions = actions;

    var description = "<div><ul class='action'>";
    actions.forEach(function (action, idx) {
        description += '<li onclick="showOrderModal('+ idx + ')"><strong>' + action.address.info.code + "</strong><br><span>" + action.address.info.address_for_pushpin + "</span>"
    })
    description += "</li></ul></div>"
    return description;
}

function showOrderModal(idx){
    var action = currentActions[idx];

    //Do what ever you were doing before with the action.
}
```

Comment: Now, I put in "showOrderModal" code to show a modal with ionic and when I close it, when I click in another pushpin it doesn't works correctly. It doesn't go to "showOrderModal" @rbrundritt

Comment: pushpin or list item? The code above is only for the list items. You haven't provided any code around adding click events to pushpins.